# Updating multiple rows returns same value instead of updating it respectively

Tags: php, rows

```
table: test1
----------
|id |name|
----------
|46 |BOB |
----------

table: test2
------------------------
|id  |name_id |job     |
------------------------
|133 |46      |NOJOB   |
------------------------
|134 |46      |NOJOB   |
------------------------
|135 |46      |NOJOB   |
------------------------
```

Hello, i have a problem to update multiple rows on the "test2.job" respectively based on the "test2.name_id which is resulted from the mysql_insert_id(); function from "test1.id" in the INSERT query and my table structure as above.

I have the form that will populated depends on how much record i have in "test2" table with a condition of "WHERE name_id = '".$_GET['id']."'" and i have specified "localhost/rfps/ztransposto.php?id=46" in the browser url address and the form will shows as what is in the test2 table above.

The thing is when i try to change and update the first and the second row it will update nothing as it only will update if i change the last row value and updates the other two rows both first and second row with the same value. Below are the source code:

1-update form page

```
<?php require_once('Connections/rfps.php'); ?>
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
 }
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE name_id = '".$_GET['id']."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

$i = 0;

echo '<table width="50%">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>ID</td>';
echo '<td>Name ID</td>';
echo '<td>Job</td>';
echo '</tr>';

echo "<form name='form_update' method='post' action='ztranspostop.php'>\n";
while ($job = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<tr>';
echo "<td>{$job['id']}<input type='hidden' name='id[$i]' value='{$job['id']}' /></td>";
echo "<td>{$job['name_id']}<input type='hidden' name='name_id[$i]' value='{$job['name_id']}' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' size='40' name='job[$i]' value='{$job['job']}' /></td>";
echo '</tr>';
++$i;
}
echo '<tr>';
echo "<td><input type='submit' value='submit' /></td>";
echo '</tr>';
echo "</form>";
echo '</table>';

?>
</body>
</html>
```

2-update query page

```
<?php require_once('Connections/rfps.php'); ?>
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$size = count($_POST['job']);

$i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
    $job= $_POST['job'][$i];
    $name_id = $_POST['name_id'][$i];

    $query = "UPDATE test2 SET job = '$job' WHERE name_id = '$name_id'";
    mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
    echo "$job<br /><br /><em>Updated!</em><br /><br />";
    ++$i;
}
?>
```

Can anyone point out which part of the codes i got it wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Learn about and fix those vulnerabilities in your code before you do anything else.

Comment: Noted, will do. Thanks for pointing that out and for the link too. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the connection between the test2.id field in the form and using it in the update query. In fact, you probably don't need the `WHERE name_id =` clause if you include the `WHERE id =` instead. This completes the association between a row in your form (the values of $i on that page) and the particular job row being updated (the values of $i on the subsequent page). Otherwise, you are only updating based on an attribute which they will all have in common (name_id) :-)

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
    $job= $_POST['job'][$i];
    $job_id = intval($_POST['id'][$i]);

    $query = "UPDATE test2 SET job = '$job' WHERE id = '$job_id'";
    mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
    echo "$job<br /><br /><em>Updated!</em><br /><br />";
    ++$i;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input and detailed explanation, your codes fixed it!! Many thanks to you ctrahey =)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just a reminder that accepting an answer is good for you, me, and the whole community :-)

Comment: Done and done, i thought it was the 'Yes' 'No' button clicked numerous times just now i noticed the tick mark lol